# mod rewrite htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to achieve te following rewrite:
The url, stenenkermis.be or www.stenenkermis.be will result in www.stenenkermis.be/2012/v1/

`www.stenenkermis.be/2012/v1/page/param/param/` needs to result in
`www.stenenkermis.be/2012/page.php?param1=&param2=` (but the parameters are optionality the user can also go to home/ without parameters)

Currently this is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stenenkermis\.be$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.stenenkermis.be/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /2012/v1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^2012/v1/([^/]+)/ /2012/$1.php [NC,R]
RewriteRule ^2012/v1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /2012/$1.php?arg1=$2&arg2=$3 [NC,R]
RewriteRule ^2012/v1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /2012/$1.php?arg1=$2&arg2=$3 [NC,R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?stenenkermis.be/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ - [F]
```

the  only problem is that my url gets redirected to 
http://www.stenenkermis.be/2012/page.php?param1=&param?= in the address bar ,I  don't want the user to see this.

Can anyone help me with figuring this htaccess out?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `R` in your rewrite flags, since it means mod_rewrite is instructed to send an HTTP redirect to the user. Use `QSA` instead.

Comment: Yes, but now my relative paths (stylesheets, images, scripts) are messed up. They are relative to the new url. Can i somehow overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Fge is right, but your rules seem to be in the *wrong order*.

Rule of thumb: always start with the most complex the go to the less complex.

And of course, add QSA instead of R in the right places:

As a suggestion I've added all the static files (it's my rule in my prod environment):

Thus:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stenenkermis\.be$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.stenenkermis.be/$1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite, but **keep on** with modified URL:
RewriteRule ^$ /2012/v1/ [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^2012/v1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /2012/$1.php?arg1=$2&arg2=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^2012/v1/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /2012/$1.php?arg1=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^2012/v1/([^/]+)/ /2012/$1.php [NC,QSA,L]

# operate with static files: forbid if not coming for original website:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?stenenkermis.be/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)(\.(css|js|htc|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico))$ - [NC,F]
```

### And now two hints:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Olivier, thanks! It works, only the log does give an 500 internal server error. I made the file web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log on the server but it keeps giving the error. Without the logging part the script works fine! Is there a way to not effect the relative paths in the websites or is this just a browser issue?

Comment: I worked it out. Just put / before the paths so it refers to the server path and not relative to the url.

Comment: @TijsProost : May I ask you to check it as valid?

Comment: @fge Yep it uses PCRE, and that what makes RewriteRules so powerful

Comment: @TijsProost If you have 500 errors, this probably means you're trying to use RewriteLog not in a real vhost (`<vhost>...</vhost>`) configuration, but in an `.htaccess` file.